# Use of Where do and Where

Tags: do

Where the animals live? Where do the animals live?

I like to know which sentence is correct or more correct? Why do is not in both sentence?

Please help me understand it.

Comment: *Do* is not in the first sentence because you didn't put it there. It's the only thing that's different between the two. Or did it come from a source that you haven't cited? There might be a context in which the first sentence makes sense (most likely in reply to something in dialogue), but as a *standalone* sentence the missing *do* is a problem.

Comment: @JasonBassford not much help unless you explain *why* we do need *do* there.

Comment: @Araucaria I was not providing an *answer*. I was *commenting*. Both asking for clarification about the source of the sentences (because it's not clear what the question about *do* not being in both sentences means unless they came from some source) and saying that both versions could be correct given the right context. (So, we don't *necessarily* need  *do*. Again, another reason why context is important and the question needs to be clarified.)

Comment: @Araucaria Person A: "That's where the animals live." Person B: ***"Where the animals live?"*** Person A: "Yes, when they aren't performing." There is nothing wrong with the lack of **be** in that dialogue. In fact, in *that* dialogue, the presence of a **be** would be odd.

Comment: @JasonBassford "be"? Anyhow, point is, the most helpful info would be why we normally would need *do* there.

Comment: @Araucaria The question is not clear. The most helpful thing would be to get the question clarified *before* attempting an answer that may well not be what is wanted. (And answering every possible scenario if only one is required would be a waste of time. As would be answering the wrong question.) But if you think the question actually is why we normally use *do*, and that it doesn't care about those times when we don't, then you can provide that answer if you wish.